# Get stdClass Object by value

Tags: php, key, stdclass

Given this stdClass structure...

```
[RecentAchievements] => stdClass Object
    (
        [1446] => stdClass Object
           (
               [3319] => stdClass Object
                   (
                       [ID] => 3319
                       [GameID] => 1446
                       [Title] => Hello World!
                       [Description] => Complete World 1-1
                       [Points] => 15
                       [BadgeName] => 03909
                       [IsAwarded] => 1
                       [DateAwarded] => 2013-10-20 19:35:46
                   )
```

I need to check the objects inside 3319, like "Title", so it'd be like:

```
$data->RecentAchievements->$gameid->ACHVIDHERE->Title;
```

To get the $gameid, it came from other object (RecentlyPlayed), this way:

```
[RecentlyPlayed] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [GameID] => 1446
                [ConsoleID] => 7
                [ConsoleName] => NES
                [Title] => Super Mario Bros
                [LastPlayed] => 2013-10-20 21:38:22
                [ImageIcon] => /Images/000385.png
                [ImageTitle] => /Images/000272.png
                [ImageIngame] => /Images/000387.png
                [ImageBoxArt] => /Images/000275.png
            )

    )

$gameid = $data3->RecentlyPlayed['0']->GameID;
```

API don't let me use the same RecentlyPlayed to get the achievement ID, i have to extract it from RecentAchievements. Is it possible?

Comment: seems pretty unlikely to me that you can get that ID when you need it to access that element. can you not get more information with your existing call to get the `$gameid`? e.g. ask it to return an array containing both values?

Comment: You mean convert the object to array and extract the ID? Maybe yes, but i was looking for something more clean (if possible).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're just after the first achievement for that particular game, you could use this hack:

```
$firstAchievement = reset($data->RecentAchievements->$gameid);
$title = $firstAchievement->Title;
```

The API is probably giving you a JSON response, so you may also want to consider this:

```
$data = json_decode($response, true);
                               ^^^^
```

The second parameter `true` turns the JavaScript objects into PHP arrays, which in most cases makes it easier to handle them, e.g.

```
$firstAchievement = reset($data['RecentAchievements'][$gameid]);
$title = $firstAchievement['Title'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use complex curly notation to reference dynamic properties of an object

```
$data->RecentAchievements->{$gameid}->{$someotherid}->Title;
```

This should give you `Hello World!`, given `$gameid` == `1446` and `$someotherid` == `3319`

Comment: Sorry if i misunderstood you, but how to give $someotherid the ID value (in this specific model, 3319)? The ACHVIDHERE is where i am supposed to put the achievement ID, i presume. So, it would be:

    `data->RecentAchievements->{$gameid}->{$someotherid}->Title;`

Comment: @DanielLemes If `ACHVIDHERE` has a value of `3319` and `$gameid` == `1446`, then you can use   `$data->RecentAchievements->{$gameid}->{ACHVIDHER}E->Title;`. Notice the `{}` around the variable and the constant.

Comment: Yes, but that's the point: access the [3319] => stdClass Object, get the value (in this particular one, 3319) and give it to a variable to create the second part, that calls the Title.

The ACHVIDHERE was just a placeholder, i don't know how to give it the value.

Comment: If you don't know that value you can use a `foreach ($object as $key => $value)` to iterate through them.